# Crashlytics pod is still using UIWebView generating the ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage

Tags: ios, cocoapods, crashlytics, google-fabric

I recently uploaded an app to **TestFlight** and I got the following warning from **Apple**:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

Due to I am not directly using any `UIWebView` at all, I did:

```
grep -r "UIWebView" .
```

And the result was:

```
Binary file ./Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics matches
```

I am using `Crashlytics (3.13.4)` which is the latest one.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 7):

Run `pod update`.

Crashlytics 3.14.0 released today with the UIWebView symbols removed to address this issue.

Answer (score 3):

As I have same issue and contacted Crashlytics Support -  they told me that **there are several tickets about this issue and they are going to resolve this as soon as possible.** Do not worry it is  just a warning ignore for now and update your SDK later.

Answer (score 2):

**Google** has to update **Crashlytics** by getting rid of the `UIWebView`. Otherwise, Apple could eventually reject the apps.